# why I can't using expect equal in my new rspec version

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm the new of the ruby code. My team member write a class Deck which implement the game set

```
class Deck
  @array = Array.new

  # create a deck of n cards
  # n <= 0 returns empty array.
  def initialize (n=1)
    @array = (0..n-1).to_a
  end
end
```

im trying to write rspec testing which is also new to us, here's the test code:

```
#!/user/bin/ruby -w
require '../deck'
require 'rspec/expectations'

describe "Deck#new" do
  context "with one parameter " do
    it "has parameter n = 0" do 
      expect(Deck.new(0)).to match_array([])
    end

    it "has parameter n = 1" do
      expect(Deck.new(1)).to eq([0])
    end

    it "has parameter n = 5" do
      expect(Deck.new(5))==([0,1,2,3,4])
    end

    it "has parameter n<0" do
      expect(Deck.new(-1))==([])
    end
  end
end
```

but when i run this test, it gives me

```
expected a collection that can be converted to an array with `#to_ary` or `#to_a`, but got #<Deck:0xb82edb74 @array=[]>
```

and the first two failed, which I don't understand. Did I miss something in my code? Thanks for help. My rspec version is the newest.

Comment: yes. I thought we are not supposed to use operator?   @Stefan

Comment: I don't think `expect(a) == b` is doing anything. The [correct syntax](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers#compare-using-==) is `expect(a).to be == b`

Comment: BTW, instead of `(0..n-1)` you can use `(0...n)` (3 dots)

Answer (score 2):

You need a method to access the cards:

```
class Deck
  def initialize (n=1)
    @array = (0..n-1).to_a
  end
  def cards
    @array
  end
end
```

In this way:

```
Deck.new(5).cards
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, change your tests to:

```
it "has parameter n = 0" do 
 expect(Deck.new(0).cards).to match_array([])
end
```

and so on...

UPDATE:
`Deck.new(n)` returns the whole object

```
Deck.new(5)
=> #<Deck:0x007fb56b0e82b0 @array=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]>
```

For this reason your test will fail... The whole object is not the same as the content of `@array` (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`).

UPDATE 2:
You can define any new method, for example the number os cards in a deck:

```
class Deck
  def initialize (n=1)
    @array = (0..n-1).to_a
  end
  def cards
    @array
  end
  def number_of_cards
    @array.size
  end
end

Deck.new(5).number_of_cards
#=> 5
```

Comment: it seems like the code my teammate wrote need to be changed slightly. Since everything methods he implemented after that is using @array. for instance:    '#returns array of n random cards
  def pick_n (n)
    (n<=0) ? @array.sample(0) : @array.sample(n)
  end'    he used this, should we change something. I am totally new with this language, please bear with me : )

Comment: without the `def cards` you will get the `Deck` object with the correct `@array`, but you cannot get the array content from the object. The `def cards` will allow you to get this information (`object.cards`), returning the `@array` content. In your test, `Deck.new(0)` is the whole object, not the content of `@array` and for this reason it fails the test.

Comment: so if I want to test another method, could I use **Deck.new(5).new_method**?  but it gives me wrong argument error.

Comment: Yes, you can test any `new_method`, but you must define it inside the `Deck`. Take a look in my updated answer.